# Increase Parse Cloud Code Function timeout time

Tags: timeout, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a Parse Cloud Code function that has to make a https request to another service, and that service may take too long to finish executing to have my function stay within the 15 second timeout. Is there anyway to increase the timeout limit above 15 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

The only cloud code that can exceed 15 seconds is a Job.

One option is to have a Cloud Function that saves information on what you want done to a row, e.g. `PendingRequest`. You can then have a job that runs every 5 minutes, checking for any records in the `PendingRequest` class and running them, saving the results, e.g. in another class called `CompletedRequest`.

If your UI needs to show completion it'll need to poll the `CompletedRequest` class to see if its request has been complete.

The main issue is that it could be up to 5 minutes before you get any results.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do that and would love to share. Grab the open source Parse Mobile SDK. Navigate to the ParsePlugins.java file, and search for socketOperationTimeout, change the two places of assignments to this variable to whatever value you like for timeout.

Compile the modified SDK and import to your mobile code.